# Enviar formulario con Cypress

Tags: javascript

Soy nuevo en [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) y estoy intentando enviar los datos de un formulario a una página en blanco. Mi problema viene a la hora de añadir la redirección a dicha página.

HTML

```
<template>
  <div class="datos">
    <h1>Datos capturados del formulario</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

TEST

```
describe('My First Test', () => {
  it('Visits the app root url', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:8080')
    cy.get('form').submit()
    cy.contains('h1', 'Prueba formulario cypress')
    cy.get('input[name=firsName]').type('Pedro')
    cy.get('input[name=secondName]').type('García Sanchez')
    cy.get('input[type="number"]').type(30)
    cy.get('input[type="email"]').type('pedro@gmail.com')
    cy.get('select')
    .select('2').should('have.value','2')
    cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()
    cy.request('http://localhost:8080/datos').its('body').should('include', '<h1>Admin</h1>')
```

El fallo esta en el cy.request ya que si pongo la ruta larga o la ruta: cy.request('/datos') no funciona.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Yo aca no veo nada vue.

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo con Vue, pero por el momento solo es javascript

Comment: Correcto. He formulado mal la preguntado, ya esta modificado

Comment: Es importante que pongas las etiquetas correctamente. porque si no algun experto de JS capaz no entra porque piensa que es un tema de vue, y viceversa ;)

Comment: vale, tienes razón. Entonces sabrías como solucionar mi problema con Cypress?

Comment: no porque yo se vue ;) ni idea de cypress, perdon, pero esperemos que un experto en js te pueda ayudar...

Comment: muchas gracias :)